# What is Infrastructure failure in firebase test lab

Tags: firebase, testing, firebase-test-lab

After testing firebase it is showing  "Infrastructure failure" what is mean by "Infrastructure failure " ? and How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

It means Firebase Test Lab hit an unusual internal error that was not recoverable or retryable.

The best way to get help with this issue is to join the [Firebase Community](https://firebase.community/) and post this question along with your matrix ID in the test_lab channel on Slack.